# please explain me what does this line var Query = req.db.driver.query; means

Tags: node.js, express

```
module.exports = {

//Admin index
index: function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('I am in indexChoicelist');
    var Query = req.db.driver.query;
    var perPages = 10;
    var page = parseInt(req.params.page) || 1;

    if( isNaN(page) || page < 1) {
        page = 1;
    }

    log.debug('>>req.body:'+ JSON.stringify(req.body));
    log.debug('>> page:'+ page);

    // var name = req.body.name || "";
    // var sku = req.body.sku;
    var deleted = req.body.deleted
```

Why do we use this req.body.deleted?

Please explain me what does this line `var Query = req.db.driver.query;` means

Comment: That means that the variable **Query** contains the value of  **req.db.driver.query**

Comment: it looks like the value is being populated via a amiddleware, or a route handler, which could be event the case from a npm that you are using, so, its hard to answer without finding that, Search in your repo including npm_modules folder and try to find the specific code